# arm(Thumb-2) compare 32 bits and convert to hex

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I run on arm(Thumb-2) and  want check if data on address that store on register r3+0x14 = `AABBCCDD`.

I think the code is :

```
ldr r3,[r0,#0x14]
ldr r2, #0xAABBCCDD
cmp r3, r2
BNE notCompareLabel
```

now I want to translate to hex that fix to Thumb-2.  I use http://armconverter.com/ to translate from arm to hex.

`ldr r3,[r0,#0x14]` -> `4369`

`cmp r3, r2` -> `9342`

but I can't translate `ldr r2, #0xAABBCCDD` with  this site.

1. Is my arm code is right?
2. I looking for software to  translate arm(Thumb-2) to hex (I not like this site)
3. why I can't translate `ldr r2, #0xAABBCCDD` ? and what is the translate to hex?

thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
ldr r2, =0xAABBCCDD
```

Why don't you use a proper assembler such as GAS (shipped with GCC)?
This ldr is a pseudo instruction. It might be translated into mov or to a load from a literal pool:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731147760.htm

If you want to patch something and need to avoid literal pools, you can do:

```
mov r2, #0xCCDD
movt r2, #0xAABB
```

Comment: and do you know software to translate arm to hex ?

Comment: As I said - yes, the GNU Assembler GAS, the Keil ARM Assembler, the IAR ARM Assembler, Microsoft's ARM Assembler etc.

Comment: witch one of them can convert from hex to arm(the opposite from arm to hex) ?

Comment: You mean from hexadecimal data to assembler code? Any disassembler, e.g. objdump (part of binutils) or the ones shipped with the other mentioned development environments.

Comment: those instructions (movt and that mov with more than 8 significant bits) are not universally supported by ARM (nor thumb-2)

Comment: @Erlkoenig do you know instructions that work on thumb2?

Comment: According to http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf mov and movt are available on Thumb 2 starting from ARMv6. If your need support for even older CPU's, you can use 4x mov and 3x orr with a shifted operand.

Comment: @Erlkoenig thank you about your softwares recommendation, but  I not need convert full program from arm assembly to hex, only one command each time, so I not found any simple tool to do it.

Comment: Converting assembly code into machine code is done by an assembler. That is the "tool" you need. So what would be simpler than using an assembler for doing an assembler's job? You could look for an assembler that does not need a linker, but I'm not sure that exists for ARM. I wouldn't be sure the time saved is worth using an unusual software with little support.

Comment: Assuming you want to assemble for a Cortex-M architecture on Debian/Ubuntu Linux, you can install gcc-arm-none-eabi, type your assembly code into a file "test.S", and run:

"arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -nostartfiles -nostdlib test.S && arm-none-eabi-objdump -d a.out"

That will quickly give you the assembled code and a hex dump of the instructions.